# Control if object is clicked or not in if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm building a small memory game. Where the user is presented by different objects that are displayed one at a time (which is done by an animation). The user can choose or not choose to click an object. The user is presented with a list indicating which objects should not be clicked, if the user clicks an object that should be clicked he gets one point. If the user decides to not click on a faulty object he should be rewarded one point as well. And the latter is my question, how can I control when the user doesn't click an object? My if statement right now only checks when the user actually clicks an object.

I'm aware that I need to move the verify function to my setTimout call for each object. But I'm not sure what to look for in the if statement?

```
function createShapes() {
                    var classes = [
                        "shape blue size200",
                        "shape size200 bluetriangle",
                    ];

                    var id = [
                        "wrong",
                        "right",
                    ];

                    var randomOrderArray = [];

                    for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
                        var randomElement = document.createElement("div");

                        randomElement.setAttribute("id", id[i]);
                        randomElement.setAttribute("class", classes[i]);
                        randomElement.classList.add();
                        randomOrderArray.push(randomElement);
                    }

                    // Calls shuffleArray
                    shuffleArray(randomOrderArray);

                    for (i = 0; i < randomOrderArray.length; i++) {
                        objectElement.appendChild(randomOrderArray[i]);
                    }
                }


                // Adds eventlisteners to shapes
                var objects = document.querySelectorAll(".shape");

                for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                    objects[i].addEventListener("click", verifyShapes);
                    });
                }

                let counter = 0;

                // Verifies clicked objects
                function verifyShapes() {
                     if (this.id == "right") {
                        points++;
                        this.removeEventListener("click", verifyShapes);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>.....</title>
    <body>
        <div class="content" id="content"></div>
        <div class="object" id="object"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the html as well.

Comment: Let's say there are 5 things that the user should *not* click on. You could start the user's score at 5, because he has not clicked any of them yet, and simply subtract 1 every time he *does* click on a wrong thing. Otherwise, you would have to credit the user for things not clicked based perhaps on a timer or upon him clicking a 'Done' button, both of which would give you the chance to run code and count the bad things not clicked.

Comment: Solved! Thank you!